# How to detect Operating System in nodejs Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, request, operating-system

How do I detect the operating system that the browser making a request to a noodejs server is being run on.

I am able to get user agent (which gives the broswer name along with some OS information) by doing:

```
request.headers['user-agent']
```

but their is a lot of jumbled information and it is not apparent that it can be filtered out with a string split.

Is there some other way to get the OS information or do I need to use regular expressions to filter out the OS name.

Comment: A simple regEx, should give you what you want eg. ->  `navigator.userAgent.match(/(?<=\().*?(?=;)/)[0]`   ps. navigator userAgent in browser gives you the same value..  On my machine it returns `"Windows NT 10.0"`  IOW: Window 10

Comment: Thanks. I figured I would have to go the regex route. I had wanted to avoid that because I wasn't sure how consistent the value would be but it seems to give correct values for all cases so far.

Comment: This may be useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/useragent